# Is there a difference between "are here also" and "are also here"

Tags: grammar

Is there a difference between `are here also` and `are also here`?

> In this street you see 2 trees, 1 mithril rock and 1 patch of wheat.
>   You look around and notice that Bob, Sara and Tom are also here.

This is my actual use case, but I wonder if one of the two makes it more implicit. My intention is to say "besides all these resources, you also see some users".
Or perhaps there's even better wording..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often, context must be used to determine the meaning of "also". If there are two nouns in the also-clause, placement of the word **also** does have implications, but they're ambiguous.

> She also had some coins in her pocket.
>
> She had some coins also in her pocket.

Does **also** imply something aforementioned which is other than coins, or which is somewhere other than her pocket, or both?

The first sentence above might imply that she had something else besides, and it was in a place other than her pocket:

**She had a five dollar bill in her hand. She also had some coins in her pocket.**

The second sentence above implies that she had something else besides and that it, too, was in her pocket:

**She had a five dollar bill in her pocket. She had some coins also in her pocket.**

But you wouldn't want a life-or-death matter to hang upon the interpretation if all you had before you was the also-sentence.

In the OP's example, the questions are: is that trio showing up in more than one place? Or is that trio showing up in this place along with something else? Placing **also** after "here" might imply they're showing up in more than one place; placing also before "here" would tend to imply that they, too, are here.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how this applies to the OP's sentences.

Comment: Sure. I'll improve the answer.